# Is the infinite intersection of nowhere dense sets empty?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ be any topological space, and consider a decreasing, countable sequence of nowhere dense sets $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset A_3 \supset \ldots$. Is $\bigcap A_n$ empty?

Edit: it seems to be true if I consider $x \in \bigcap A_n$ and then take a sequence of balls $B_n$ and then say that any open subset of this ball must intersect one of the $A_n$, contradicting the no-where denseness of the $A_n$.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you think of some examples?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I am trying to prove this as part of a larger question about baire spaces. I am unable to think of examples for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the intersection is in general far from empty.

For an easy example - working in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology - let $A_i=\{0\}\cup\{n\in\mathbb{N}: n>i\}$. Then $\bigcap A_i=\{0\}\not=\emptyset$.

More generally, suppose $(A_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is *any* descending sequence of nowhere dense sets, and let $B$ be some nowhere dense set disjoint from all the $A_i$s. Then if we let $C_i=A_i\cup B$, we have $$C_1\supset C_2\supset ...\quad\mbox{ and }\quad\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}}C_i\supseteq B.$$ But the $C_i$s are still nowhere dense. So the intersection can really be quite large - a whole other arbitrary nowhere-dense set!